# Outlook add-in command not showing in Outlook 2016 ribbon

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, office-addins, office365-apps

I have been converting the manifest for my Outlook add-in to use a add-in command to show an icon in the ribbon if the user is on Outlook 2016. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get an icon to show up in the ribbon.

The add-in works fine on other clients.

Here is an anonymized version the manifest file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xsi:type="MailApp"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
           xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0">
  <Id>892bf749-7601-428e-a658-1d32b883a712</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>My Name</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Addin" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Description goes here." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/icon.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/icon.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.sydience.com/?page_id=7" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/v1.1/AppRead/Home/Home.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>350</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/v1.1/AppRead/Home/Home.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>350</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
      <PhoneSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/v1.1/AppRead/Home/Home.html" />
      </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Description resid="residDescription" />
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadMyAddinGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Tooltip resid="paneReadTipTitle" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="myaddin-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="myaddin-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="myaddin-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources> 
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="myaddin-icon-16" DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/v1.1/Images/myaddin-icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="myaddin-icon-32" DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/v1.1/Images/myaddin-icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="myaddin-icon-80" DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/v1.1/Images/myaddin-icon-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://myaddin-host.com/v1.1/AppRead/Home/Home.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="residDescription" DefaultValue="My Outlook add-in" />
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Addin" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Show Pan" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadTipTitle" DefaultValue="More text here" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="More text here" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="More text here" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
   </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bt:String` resources for the `Tooltip` and `Description` elements have to be in the `bt:LongStrings` element. Try replacing:

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:String id="residDescription" DefaultValue="My Outlook add-in" />
  <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Addin" />
  <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Show Pan" />
  <bt:String id="paneReadTipTitle" DefaultValue="More text here" />
  <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="More text here" />
  <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="More text here" />
</bt:ShortStrings>
```

With:

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
  <bt:String id="residDescription" DefaultValue="My Outlook add-in" />
  <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Addin" />
  <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Show Pan" />
  <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="More text here" />
</bt:ShortStrings>
<bt:LongStrings>
  <bt:String id="paneReadTipTitle" DefaultValue="More text here" />
  <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="More text here" />
</bt:LongStrings>
```

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it.